# Review first post and late answer tasks and edit

Tags: feature-request, bug, late-answers, first-post-review

Today I was reviewing *First Posts* and *Late Answers*, and in several posts, I wasn't able to edit it. Due to a bug on site, when I pressed edit, no message was telling me why I couldn't edit the post (I'm using *Google Chrome* latest version).

When I opened the link on another tab, I found out that the post had already an edit on the queue to be reviewed. I found at least 4 posts in this situation today, and I started to wonder: *why the post was sent to me for review if someone already has an edit on the queue?*

You could say I could flag the post if it was really bad. However, even if I did that, I was going to do it in an outdated version of the post (maybe some other reviewer was able to improve a lot the post). I could press *No action needed*, but the post needed an edit, so it would be wrong...

My suggestion is to not send to people whose reputation is below 2k (like me) posts that have pending edits - the only reasonable option I have is skip the post. If a user that is unable to edit takes any other action would certainly be to increase review count (which would be really bad).

Comment: This feature has been requested already: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298797/editing-a-post-during-review-doesnt-show-an-edit-not-possible-message (or "requested a bug fix")

Comment: "On MSO and MSE combined, this bug has now been reported more than 10 times ..." - Glorfindel [on MSE Sep 7 at 11:43](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298797/editing-a-post-during-review-doesnt-show-an-edit-not-possible-message#comment977074_298797). Let's turn it up to 11.

Comment: the post was marked as a dup, but the other post does not contain the suggestion I've made - which is the core of the post - __My suggestion is to not send to people whose reputation is below 2k (like me) posts that have pending edits - the only reasonable option I have is skip the post. If a user that is unable to edit takes any other action would certainly be to increase review count (which would be really bad).__ - It would fix the bug AND prevent problems when editing...